# How to display a different value on top of bar

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am working on graph and they are working fine. I am using MPChart library. It shows the accurate calculated value on the top of every bar. Here we can see that the value displaying on the top of bar is the accurate bar limit.

[image]

Now I have an another requirement in which I have to display another value on the top of the bars that is differ from its limit value

[image]

please let me know that how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [`ValueFormatter`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface). You simply write a class that implements this interface and override the method:

```
String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler)
```

Put inside the method the logic you need to convert the actual value into the value you want to display. For example, the following `ValueFormatter` simply multiplies the actual chart value by 10:

```
public class TenTimesValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {
    @Override
    protected String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return Integer.toString(value * 10);
    }
}
```

You can consume it like this:

```
barData.setValueFormatter(new TenTimesValueFormatter());
```

You will probably need:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
mChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

**Update:** if you need a `ValueFormatter` that simply takes values from a backing array, you could do something like this:

```
public class IndexValueFormatter implements IValueFormatter {

    private final String [] values;

    public IndexValueFormatter(String[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        int index = Math.round(value);

        if (index < 0 || index >= values.length || index != (int)value)
            return "";

        return values[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David for your precious time and kind effort but the problem is still remain as this process is changing the bottom of XAxis data that I dont want to change. I want to change the data displaying on the top of every bar, not bottom values or can say the observation name that I am displaying in the bottom of each bar.

Comment: @Devraj please check the updated answer. You just have to set the ValueFormatter on your barData.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, it is working now. but there is a query that it displays only one float value over all the bars, can we have arraylist on the place of float value so that every bar can have a different value.

Comment: @Devraj this isn't really a code-for-me service but I'm happy to help anyway. So I updated the answer with the code for what you want. Please accept the answer (green tick next to answeR)